# JAVA: Pasar argumentos al jvm

Tags: java, jvm

espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
Intento configurar una librería en Java pero me da error, viendo su documentación, me recomiendan hacer esto:

"Java 9 (JPMS) introduces strong encapsulation to improve security. When you're running your application on Java 9 or higher in classpath mode (legacy mode) you have to pass the arguments below to the JVM for proper execution without any errors/warnings. For Synthetica V3 you have to use 'synthetica.base' as module name - for more information take a look at the README.TXT which is part of each download package."

Los argumentos serían estos:

```
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.table=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.plaf.synth=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
// required for SyntheticaAddons only
// --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED
```

No tengo idea donde debo ingresarlos y he buscado documentación por todos lados.
Uso Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas pasarlo como argumento cuando ejecutas tu applicacion por ejemplo

```
java --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.table=ALL-UNNAMED  -jar myapplication.jar
```

Desde los IDEs(Eclipse,Netbeans, Intellij) debe venir una opcion para pasar esos arguemntos sin la necesidad de salir de ellos, dale una busqueda en google sobre como pasar argumentos en Netbeans

updated

click derecho sobre tu proyecto en Netbeans, seleccionas la opcion run y ahi debe venir una caja de texto llamado vm options, ahi deberias pasar esos argumentos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso es lo que no encuentro y recurrí acá a preguntar. Mi aplicación la hice y ejecuto en netbeans. No se donde ingresar estos argumentos en Netbeans.

Comment: actualize la respuesta, prubea pasando esos argumentos en la opcion llamda vm options @ZenonBurgos

Comment: Así era exactamente, ahora el problema es otro pero para ingresar los argumentos es justo como dices, gracias colega.